# C# приложение зависает без sleep

Tags: c#, отладка, sleep

Проблема довольно странная - если поставить sleep меньше 700, то где-то на 10 итерации прога намертво зависает. 700 - достаточно много, долго думает... но работает. 
Задача достаточно простая: загрузить страницу по адресу из массива; кликнуть на ней; загрузить другую...

моя реализация: 
в цикле обрабатываем каждый элемент массива.
загружаем его в браузер. 
Далее перехватываем событие что страничка загружена и выполняем отдельный метод (нажимает те самые кнопки). 
Когда метод закончит - флаг wb2scanned = true; 
Как только флаг срабатывает - переходим к следующей итерации...

а вот на практике что-то ерунда получилась((( Либо тормоза со sleep(700), либо зависает (при том чем меньше sleep() - Тем быстрее виснет.

```
     private void _webBrowser2(object sender, WebBrowserProgressChangedEventArgs e)
            {
              int max = (int)Math.Max(e.MaximumProgress, e.CurrentProgress);
              int min = (int)Math.Min(e.MaximumProgress, e.CurrentProgress);
              if (min.Equals(max) && webBrowser2.Document.GetElementById("body")!=null) //загрузилось?
              {
                bool frmtch = true; //защита от повторного срабатываения.

                if (wb2loaded ==false && frmtch!=false){
                      wb2loaded = true; 
                      filter_start(); //Функция нажатий
                    }
              }
            }

 void Filter_stratClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
webBrowser2.ProgressChanged += new WebBrowserProgressChangedEventHandler(_webBrowser2);

         foreach(string f in lines){ //lines - массив со ссылками
            f_id= f.Trim(';');

            wb2loaded = false;
            wb2scanned = false; //в конце своей работы filter_start() присвоит ей true;

            webBrowser2.Navigate(f_id); 

            //ждем пока загрузит браузер...
            while(wb2scanned!=true){
                Application.DoEvents();
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(700);
        }
      }
```

Comment: Помоему проще для данной задачи использовать энумератор с yield. В приложении после клика вызывать Next

Answer (score 1):

Используйте асинхронный код.

```
async void Filter_stratClick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    // ...

    wb2scanned = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();
    webBrowser2.Navigate(f_id); 
    await wb2scanned.Task;

    // ...
}
```

Внутри `filter_start`:

```
wb2scanned.SetResult(null);
```

Comment: А вы поле нужного типа создать в классе не забыли случайно?..

Comment: не исключаю, не так давно с# учу. (((((

Comment: а как его создать? )

Comment: э... а как вы раньше это делали?